# ADT Plugin issue with user home

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm getting an error from the emulator while it's starting. I know that there is a known issue with the ADT Plugin and the user home, but I think my problem is a little different.

When I try to launch the emulator I'm getting this error:

```
PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\AdriÃ¡n\.android\avd\sda.avd/config.ini
```

As you can see the username is changed from Adrián (Which is configured in the ADT) to AdriÃ¡n and it's not recognized by the system. I tried to set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME and user.home variables but it's not working.

I guess that the problem is the accent in my username. Any ideas?
Regards.

Comment: may I ask how were you setting your ANDROID_SDK_HOME ??

Comment: It's configured as an environment variable in Windows. And user.home as string substitution in Eclipse.

Comment: @Raykud I search for all the .android instances and the only path I get is: C:\Users\Adrián\.android so the AVD is getting the path by default which is correct. The problem is when de á from Adrian is converted to Ã¡ (AdriÃ¡n) and the path is not recognized. I don't find any way to solve this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I found a workaround:

The problem is that if you have a username with latin, cyrilic or other non english character it's going to fail.

The steps I followed to solve it were:

1. Copy directory "[emulator_name].avd" to some place where the path will not contain special symbols symbols (I placed the file in "D:\Emulators[emulator_name].avd).
2. Open the file [emulator_name].ini in your first directory (In my case C:\Users\AdriÃ¡n.android\avd)
3. Change "path=C:\Users\Adrián.android\avd[emulator_name].avd" to "path=D:\Emulators[emulator_name].avd"
4. Save, close and relaunch your emulator.

Answer (score 5):

As Nucklear said the problem is the character coding: 
My solution:

Open the emulator ini file with a text editor (e.g. PSPad) and change the default UTF-8 coding to your country default code which contain the non-english letters( in my case ISO-8859-2 ). Maybe after the change you need to rewrite those characters what cause the problems.

The ini files are in the ...Users\UserName.android\avd  directory and named like the emulator you created before with the AVD manager.

(Sorry for my bad english.)